# archive php sql date()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I've started something I don't know how to finish. I've built a table called 'blog'. In the blog table there is a column, `date`. I use the `date()` function to retrieve this column: 
"1360225336".

I want [Archives](http://php.net/archive/2013.php) by year followed by month:

-2013

9.September
.
.
.
3.March
2.February
1.January

-2012

12.December
.
.
.
3.March
2.February
1.January

```
  <?php


        $query_o = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blog`")or die(mysql_error());

        while($row_o = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_o)){

        $new_date_y = date("Y", $row_o[date]);
        $new_date_m = date("n", $row_o[date]);


    $query_h = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blog` where date = $new_date_y ")or die(mysql_error());

    while($row_h = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_h)){

    $new_date_m1 = date("n", $row_o[date]);

echo'<ul>$new_date_y</ul>';
echo'<li>$new_date_m1</il>';
}



        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you take a few minutes to translate this to English that we can have easier time understanding? What is archive? It's difficult to tell what you're going on about.

Comment: I've corrected your English and (hopefully) maintained your meaning.  I suggest in future you write your question in your own language and then feed it through an autotranslator (like google, http://translate.google.com/) before posting it. Google is not perfect but it will likely be more readable than your current level of English proficieny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying a lot of new thing finally i succeed

```
<?php


$result = mysql_query("select distinct FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%Y') as year from blog ") or die(mysql_error());

$years = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
$years[] = $row['year'];

$one_year_posts = array();

foreach($years as $year){



$result1 = mysql_query("select distinct FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%M') as m from blog where FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%Y') = '$year'") or die(mysql_error());

$ms = array();

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
$ms[] = $row1['m'];

$one_year_posts = array();

foreach($ms as $m){

$date= $year;
$date.= " ";
$date.= $m;

echo <<<PRINT
     <li><a href='search.php?archie=$date'>$date</a></li>
PRINT;

}


}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$result = mysql_query("select distinct YEAR(date) as year from blog ") or die(mysql_error());

$years = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
      $years[] = $row['year'];

$one_year_posts = array();

foreach($years as $year){
    echo $year."<br/>";
    //echo "select * from blog where YEAR(date) = '$year'";
     $result1 = mysql_query("select * from blog where YEAR(date) = '$year'") or die(mysql_error());

     while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
      $one_year_posts[] = $row1;

     foreach($one_year_posts as $post){
     //echo $post['date']."<br>";
      $months.=  date('m F',strtotime($post['date'])).", ";

  }
  echo $months = rtrim($months," ,");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `blog` GROUP BY YEAR(`Date`), MONTH(`Date`);
```

If you also need `day`, just add `` , DAY(`Date`) `` at the end.

Comment: you can't group by year/month b/c the date column looks like unix-timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("select distinct FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%Y') as year from blog ") or die(mysql_error());

$years = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
      $years[] = $row['year'];

$one_year_posts = array();

foreach($years as $year){
    echo "<br/>-".$year."<br/>";
     $result = mysql_query("select * from blog where FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%Y') = '$year'") or die(mysql_error());

     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
      $one_year_posts[] = $row;

     foreach($one_year_posts as $post){
        echo strftime('%d %B',$post['date']).", ";
  }
}
```

Note: Use mysqli_ instead of mysql_ functions. The latter is deprecated and no longer maintained.

Comment: thank for your answer... its give me just 2013 (year) how i can to do '<ul>2013<li>September</li><li>February</li><li>January</li></ul>' +1

Comment: @user2262606 there was an error. I updated my answer. check it now.

Comment: now its give me '2013 10 January, 10 January, 10 January, 10 January, 11 January, 11 January, 11 January, 11 January, 11 January, 14 January, 15 January, 15 January, 15 January, 15 January...' something wrong here

Comment: @user2262606 that is what you asked right? The remaining is just a formatting issue. If you want more fields to be displayed just use $post array in the last loop and do some formatting. (Any way I did a little formatting update).

Comment: i want just month i change       echo "<li>".strftime('%B',$post['date'])."</li>"; but its not good... i want just once january and month after (without double)

Comment: i need somthing with  foreach i think... for not double

Comment: @user2262606 The script just shows you the content of the table. I can't recommend any specific filtering b/c i don't know the table structure.